# COBOLII-MB 2.xx

Tags: dos, dos-exe

I have a really old cobol program that was used to store some data, the company is no loger active and the program had to receive a key every 3 months. What tools I can use to reverse a cobol program? I tried to use ida but didn't have any success, I have some experience reversing .net

Comment: IDA does support disassembly of DOS programs, what exactly was wrong with this one?

Comment: Hi Igor, Thanks for the reply I managed to make some progress on ida, I believe my mistake was to try to treat it a ms-dos file now I'm using it as 16bits binary

Comment: so it is not a DOS EXE file? how do you run it then?

Comment: Forget what I said my progress was useless, I'm prety sure the problem is I'm in a 64bits system trying to reverse 16bits, since I can't run 16bits I believe that is why I'm geting error when using it as ms-dos file. I'll try to run a VM with windows XP and see if I can make any progress. Also IDA can handle 16bits ms-dos?

Comment: yes, IDA can definitely disassemble 16-bit MS-DOS exe file, and it (IDA)runs on 64-bit systems. Please edit the question and describe what exactly you're trying and what "doesn't work".